# text is stacks on top of itself

Tags: html, css, text

[image][image]

I have a weird problem inside my introtext div I have some `p` tags with text inside of that I have some spans to give certain words a highlighted color.

However now my text is literally on top of each other anybody has an idea what is causing this?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}
.bluetxt {
  color: #0084FF;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#introheader {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  font-family: alternate;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-weight: 800;
}
#introtxt {
  font-family: alternate;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
  margin-top: 4%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p id="introheader"><span class="bluetxt">LEO CLUB DE 4 AMBACHTEN</span>
  </p>
  <p id="introtxt"><span class="bluetxt">Leo club de 4 ambachten</span> is een servicevereniging of serviceclub voor enthousiaste jongvolwassenen (18-33) uit de regio Gent-Zelzate (BE) en Zeeuws-Vlaanderen (NL). De leden organiseren <span class="bluetxt">fundraisers</span> en
    ondersteunen met de opbrengst daarvan <span class="bluetxt">sociale projecten</span>. Op die manier krijgen de leden de kans om zichzelf te ontplooien en belangrijke vaardigheden te ontwikkelen.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove float:left and position relative from .bluetext as it is not required. For the rest a jsfiddle would be useful.

Comment: Why is a jsfiddle useful if the code is provided as a stack snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your floating and positioning is not necessary here (at least in the context of your given code). Remove the `loat: left;` and `position: relative;` and the `p` tags will behave as normal.

To make the `p` tags not overlap anymore, specify a line height, e.g. `line-height: 12pt;`. Maybe they're inheriting a `line-height:0` from one of the parents.

Sidenote: A font-size in vw is very unusual. Better provide it as `px` or `pt` and use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to make the font-size responsive.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.bluetxt {
  color: #0084FF;
}
#introheader {
  font-family: alternate;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-weight: 800;
}
#introtxt {
  font-family: alternate;
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-top: 4%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p id="introheader"><span class="bluetxt">LEO CLUB DE 4 AMBACHTEN</span>
  </p>
  <p id="introtxt"><span class="bluetxt">Leo club de 4 ambachten</span> is een servicevereniging of serviceclub voor enthousiaste jongvolwassenen (18-33) uit de regio Gent-Zelzate (BE) en Zeeuws-Vlaanderen (NL). De leden organiseren <span class="bluetxt">fundraisers</span> en
    ondersteunen met de opbrengst daarvan <span class="bluetxt">sociale projecten</span>. Op die manier krijgen de leden de kans om zichzelf te ontplooien en belangrijke vaardigheden te ontwikkelen.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no succes :( still have the same problems i removed all float and position specifications from the P tags and the SPAN tags but text is still running over eachother. Thx for the side note i'll keep it in mind :).

Comment: Ok another possibility is the `width: 80%` - have you tried without that specifiction or with `100%`?

Comment: just tried it with a 100% still on top of eachother is there a way to upload a picture then i could show you what I mean

Comment: Ok, are you sure you're editing the right file? Yes you can upload a picture directly to your question, if you edit it. Just click the image button

Comment: yes I am editing the correct file i uploaded a picture in the question where you can see the txt on top of eachtother

Comment: ok now we are talking :) can you show the web inspectors output for the `p` tags? Are there any other positionings applied? What about the line-height?

Comment: uploaded a new image with the output :) and line-height is not specified anywhere in the document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124720/discussion-between-andreas-and-pieter).